# How to change font base on props and set default if there is no prop

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

The question is pretty simple, i have a text, which have a default prop, `fontSize`, problem is i want to have props to change that size when needed, so i set default font and a props to change font, but i really don't know what is the right way to do this.

Here is my did'nt work solution:

The props called `textStyle`, i define by using typescript interface `textStyle: TextStyle`

I tried to have conditions  in `style` like

```
style={textListStyle?.fontSize ?? 15}   <== not work
```

The complier complain

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: TextProps | Readonly<TextProps>): Text', gave the following error.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp<TextStyle>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: TextProps, context: any): Text', gave the following
```

error.

And i tried

```
style={!textListStyle?.fontSize ? 15 : textListStyle?.fontSize}
```

Same issue, so what is the best solution?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to really understand what you are trying to do.
For What I understood, you have a prop and  you try to define a certain fontSize when prop is true and another one when it's not.

I would do :

```
style={{fontSize: textListStyle.fontSize ? 15 : 20 }}
```

Or if your "textListStyle?.fontSize" is an integer:

```
style={{fontSize: textListStyle?.fontSize ?? 15}}
```